# expressJS nested sequelize ORM query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

My schema goes like this
accounts -> leads -> enquires
I want to query using accountId to get only all relavent enquires as list which are linked to leads.

Thanks in advnace           .

Comment: the relations are all 1-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the include option.

```
const accountId = 123;

const enquiries = await Enquiry.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Lead,
      where: { accountId },
    },
  ],
});
```